# Map regex route to document apache xampp

Tags: node.js, apache, xampp

I created a little dev server with express. What I'm doing is mapping the first part of the URL and accepting anything after the `/`.

(I know the way I am finding the file is not ideal with the `../` in the middle of the path, I just did it because it's a simple dev server)

```
app.get("/main/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../dist/main.html"));
});
```

So if, for example, I enter at `localhost/main/KASDKJASJKD`, it will open the `main.html` document. That is exactly what want.

In production, however, the server will be an APACHE server. I am testing the project in a XAMPP server, but I am unable to achieve the same routing results, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you show what you're doing in Apache? How are you doing the routing?

Comment: I am just separating the project into folders with an `index.html` inside of it and putting it inside `htdocs` folder. So for this route for example i only have a `main` folder with the one `index.html` inside of it. I know nothing about this kind of server, this is the way i found on the internet to do this.

Comment: Why not just run your express server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.htaccess` to do something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^main/(.*) /main[R=301,L]
```

Create an `.htaccess` file in your DocumentRoot and paste that.